# Laravel hasMany relationship returning undefined method

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Model:

```
class Order extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'orders';

    public function orderItems(){
        return $this->hasMany('OrderItem');
    }

    public static function findByUserMonthYear($user_id, $month, $year){
        return Order::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
            ->where('month', '=', $month)
            ->get();
        // ->where('year', '=', $year);
    }

}
```

And of course I have an `OrderItem` class

```
class OrderItem extends Eloquent{ ...
```

But if I do:

```
$order = Order::findByUserMonthYear(Auth::user()->id, Date::getDate(), 2014);

$order->orderItems();
```

I get the following:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderItems()
```

What am I doing wrong? If I were to change the statement to `Order::with('orderItems')` the relationship seems to work fine, but I'd like to delete all the `orderItems` associated to the current `Order`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `->get()` within you findByUserMonth is returning a Collection. If this query returns only one collection then use the `->first()` instead, but if your query returns multiple results then eager load the results of orderItems like so;

```
public static function findByUserMonthYear($user_id, $month, $year){
    return self::with('orderItems')->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
        ->where('month', '=', $month)
        ->get();
    // ->where('user_id', '=', $year);
}
```

Then you can access the results like so;

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
    {{$order->orderItem}}
@endforeach
```

This is because the return being a collection, so you have to loop through them. The use `{{$order->orderItem}}` to access the results

Im not too sure on this but i think you can delete all the models within a hasMany like so; `$order->orderItem()->delete();` as the return of `orderItem()` is a Query\Builder instance.

Comment: Thanks Matt – using `->first()` did it, and in fact that meant that the original `$order->orderItems()->delete()` worked great.

Answer (score -2):

your second class must be extends Order class 
use this line for OrderItem class :

```
class OrderItem extends Order {
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: when you have extend a class with Eloquent your another sub classes that them extends with first class so extends with Eloquent  @MattBurrow